# allow zero (0) in if checking javascript

Tags: javascript

I use present or not as flag then perform relevant action. Like in my case I do something with stock or grade or both. Guess what is the problem?

```
stock = parseInt(req.body.stock),
grade = parseInt(req.body.grade),

var update = {};

if(stock){
  update = {'data.$.stock':stock}
}

if(grade){
  update = {'data.$.grade':grade}
}

if(stock && grade){
  update = {
    'data.$.grade':grade,
    'data.$.stock':stock
  }
}
```

There will be a bug if stock `0` is allowed in this case. So if inventory is zero, the bug will occur. Because it doesn't pass `if(stock){}`, hmm how to resolve this?

I don't want to write if stock is not `undefined` && stock is not `null`, that's too long.

Comment: `if (stock == null)` will be true when `stock` is *either* `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: `stock` will never even be `undefined` or `null` it will either be a number or `NaN`.

Comment: "I don't want to write if stock is not `undefined` && stock is not `null`, that's too long." That's an odd reason, considering you were willing to write 20x that in your question here.

Comment: Too long? Too bad. Either stop using `undefined` the way you're using it, or deal with the fallout :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simplify the code by assigning to a property, instead of assigning a whole object.

```
stock = parseInt(req.body.stock, 10), // use radix as well
grade = parseInt(req.body.grade, 10),

var update = {};

if (stock >= 0) { 
    update['data.$.stock'] = stock; // set property
}

if (grade >= 0) {
    update['data.$.grade'] = grade; // set property
}

// skip part for assigning both
```

Comment: nice but it doesn't answer my question. I want stock can be `0` lol

Comment: @ThianKianPhin: Nina didn't specifically call it out, but note the `if (stock >= 0)` and `if (grade >= 0)` which will only be true if the values were successfully parsed as numbers and are not `NaN`. So it *does* do what you said you want (provided neither can be negative).

Comment: @ThianKianPhin: And if negative numbers are valid, there's always `if (stock <= Infinity) {` -- the only value returned by `parseInt` for which that *isn't* true is `NaN`, which is what you get when you `parseInt(undefined)` or `parseInt(null)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see, so this is the most elegant solution so far. `parseInt` did the job well here.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `isNaN()`. Like

```
if (!isNaN(stock))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Answer (score 4):

Simply compare stock being greater than or equal to 0:

`if (stock >= 0)`

Comment: Greater or equal at least :) The OP wants stock zero to be valid.

Comment: I don't know what `grade` might be, are we sure it can't be negative? I'm thinking `stock` can't be...